# Template vs Class in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Consider the following example, and please note the `setActive` function in `app-bar.js`.

Now as it stands, if I click `Home` or `Plan` from `app-bar.html`, the `activeTab` property in `app.js` is updated appropriately. However, if I click the middle button, which invokes the aforementioned function, I receive the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: activeTab is not defined`. Moreover, if I change the setter to `this.activeTab = newTab`, no error is thrown, yet the value is not bound back to `activeTab` in `app.js`

What is going on here? Why is the DOM template the only piece of my component that's able to see/interact with `activeTab`? Am I missing necessary syntax in my class? If so, please provide documentation.

I was banging my head on my desk for a while, and on a whim I deciced to put `activeTab = 'Home'` on the `click.trigger` itself, and it magically works, yet I have no understanding why. I do not like the idea of updating model values in template, so I'd like to pass the event to JS and have that update the model, but as we can see, it doesn't work.

Let me know if you need any additional information.

**app.js**

```
export class App {
    activeTab = 'Home';
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="app-bar"></require>
    <h4>ActiveTab via App.js: ${activeTab}</h4>
    <app-bar></app-bar>
</template>
```

**app-bar.js**

```
export class AppBar {
    setActiveTab(newTab) {
        activeTab = newTab;
    }
}
```

**app-bar.html**

```
<template>
  <button click.trigger="activeTab = 'Home'">Home</button>
  <button click.trigger="setActiveTab('Assess')">Assess</button>
  <button click.trigger="activeTab = 'Plan'">Plan</button>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a place to test this out, but does it work if you change it to `this.activeTab = newTab;`?

Comment: @tcigrand It doesnt, I mentioned that in the last sentence of the second paragraph. So stumped on this one!

Comment: Ok. It looks like the you've got some issues with the scope of each component. AppBar can't see into App. You should pass the App's activeTab value to AppBar. You should be able to follow the Custom Elements section on http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.7/doc/article/cheat-sheet

Comment: Following how they pass `to` into the `SayHello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
export class AppBar {
    setActiveTab(newTab) {
        activeTab = newTab; // <---- what is `activeTab`?  It's not defined anywhere!
    }
}
```

You probably want to do something like this:

**app-bar.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class AppBar {
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) activeTab;

    setActiveTab(newTab) {
        this.activeTab = newTab;
    }
}
```

**app.html**

```js
<template>
    <require from="app-bar"></require>
    <h4>ActiveTab via App.js: ${activeTab}</h4>
    <app-bar active-tab.bind="activeTab"></app-bar>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was along these lines. And it seems that `app-bar` is able to prototypically inherit `activeTab` from `app` without having to define it as an attribute on the component - which would be helpful if I didnt' need to bind back up the tree. Very similar to angular scopes if that's the case, but different from React's concept of `this.props.activeTab` That said, if I wish to bind back to `app`, it looks as though I'll need the `active-tab.bind` syntax. (Along with the necessary imports in the class itself) Do I have that correct?

Comment: Just a follow up - looks like the issue I was experiencing with templates inheriting without a binding is a regression: https://twitter.com/AureliaEffect/status/686662742086828032

Comment: oh man- I forgot to post an update here- I had run your issue by the team- it's definitely the bug, we're working on the fix: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/pull/244
should be released soon!